# Able to create accounts via Postman, Issues creating from React

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm working on a project that has a React/Spring Boot/MYSQL stack and I'm getting an error reading "POST 415: SyntaxError:  Unexpected end of input at line 67"  Below is line 67, and below that is the function it's a part of:

`}).then(res => res.json())`

Function:

```
  handleRegisterSubmit(e, data) {
    console.log('submitting')
    let stringer = JSON.stringify(data)
    console.log(stringer)
    // console.log(data)
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('/api/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => res.json())    
    .then(res => {      
      // debugger
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({
        auth: res.auth,
        user: res.data.user
      })
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

I logged the stringified data being sent in the function and was able to create the account with that same string from Postman.  Since it works from Postman, I'm thinking there's something wrong with how I'm posting this to the DB but I'm having a hard time figuring out what.  I've used this same function with React before with Rails/Node w Postgres as the backend, and I'm not certain if there's something I need to be doing differently for the stack I'm using for this current project.  If anybody has any suggestions as to how I could/should troubleshoot further from here I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Comment: Update:  I was sending mode: 'no-cors' as one of the headers to fix a 403 error in the fetch, and by doing this, it ignored the content-type of application/json and sent it as plain text instead.  I decided to remove that header and am now troubleshooting the 403 error further.  I've pasted the text of the full error below:

Comment: Failed to load http://investedu.herokuapp.com/v1.0/register: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back-end Dev I'm working with was able to figure out how to disable the CORs requirements and that resolved the issue.  Will mark as answered ASAP.